# I am trying to convert a numpy array to PIL.Image. But it is giving black images. The numpy array is returned by pyramid_gaussian method from skimage

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

Here is my code

```
   import numpy as np
   from PIL import Image
   from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
   image =  Image.open('/home/sumith/Downloads/AFW/testimages/3854178896.jpg')
   rows, cols, dim = np.asarray(image).shape
   pyramid = tuple(pyramid_gaussian(image, downscale=2,))

   count = 0
   for pyr in pyramid[0:8]:
   row, col, dim = (np.asarray(pyr).shape)
   count += 1
   #io.imsave('/home/sumith/imagepyramids/'+count.__str__()+".jpg", pyr)
   print(type(pyr))
   image = Image.fromarray(pyr.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
   image.save('/home/sumith/imagepyramids/'+count.__str__()+".jpg")
```

when I print the type(pyr) it is showing as  but when I try to convert and save it from PIL image all the images in the pyramid will be black. but if i save it using io.imsave it is working fine .I need the image pyramid's image to be fed into a neural network so if i can feed it as PIL.Image then it will be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance!! The black image looks like this [black-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGFP0.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the values in `pyr`. Maybe they are values between 0 and `, while your RGB image is expected to be with values between 0 and 255.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem for me!